# How to translate "a closer" in French?

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, demande-de-mot

In the context of sales, how would you translate the word “closer”? In English it's not a negative word and I'm looking for the same in French. "Commercial" is salesperson but not all salespeople are closers. And I want a French word that describes great salespeople, without any negative connotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On n'a pas présenté une définition du mot qu'on veut traduire. Un *closer* est celui qui [*close*](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=closer&allowed_in_frame=0). Les réponses traitent de la [qualité](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14694) du vendeur, de sa [performance](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14706) et du *baseball*<sup>1</sup>, des courses de [chevaux](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14696). On y fait allusion mais il s'agit de l'idée de *clore* (voir verbe [to close](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/close)  + objet 9. to formally accept an agreement, *they closed the deal*; É.-U. aussi: (phrasal) close on, *they closed on the deal*, *M.-W. Learners*), de la [clôture](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cl%C3%B4ture), dans le sens de *mettre un terme* aux négociations lorsqu'on en est arrivé à une entente, conclure. Une autre manière de l'exprimer consiste à dire *[mener](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mener) à bout*, à terme des négociations, jusqu'à l'ultime conclusion soit l'entente; le *[meneur](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/meneur) d'affaires* dans un sens relié est vieilli.

Dans le contexte de la vente on fait assurément référence à la quantité, à celle ou celui qui vend *beaucoup* (volume); on pourrait utiliser en préfixe [super](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=1397)/[hyper](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3569) avec vendeur pour marquer la supériorité des bons vendeurs ou leur éméritat. D'un registre tout aussi léger, on pourrait choisir de recycler un terme ou d'en inventer un (on a noté dans un [commentaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/14689/how-to-translate-a-closer-in-french#comment28209_14706) que *finaliseur/finalisateur* n'existaient pas.). Personnellement je trouve le [**finisseur**](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/finisseur) excellent. Il a d'autres acceptions techniques (celui qui applique le finissage(la finition) d'un produit; une [machine](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finisseur)) mais aussi celle de l'*[a]thlète, coureur ou cheval apte à fournir l'effort particulier que réclame la partie finale d'une épreuve ou d'une course* (*Ac.9*; aussi [*TLFi*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/finisseur), [*Larousse*](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/finisseur/33827?q=finisseur#33769)).<sup>2</sup> Mais contrairement au *releveur de fin de partie*, il participe à toute l'épreuve. Cette référence sportive partage avec celle du baseball l'idée de terminer bien, et se prête au jeu avec des expressions comme *atteindre des cibles*, les *records de ventes*, les *équipes de vendeurs*; on peut selon moi imaginer un *tableau des finisseurs* qui affiche les noms et le décompte des *points* en ordre décroissant. C'est une idée d'adaptation du substantif *a closer* pour le domaine de la vente.

---

<sub>1. La piste du baseball est intéressante même si le *closer* a aussi un sens plus générique. Différemment du *stoppeur* de *Wikipédia* dont une réponse traite, au *GDT* on a choisi [*releveur de fin de partie*](http://www.granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8350578) alors que *Termium* a recensé pour un synonyme (*finishing pitcher*), le [*lanceur finisseur*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&index=alt&__index=alt&srchtxt=CLOSER) (voir fiche 2, *La tête de lard John Rocker, le lanceur finisseur des Indians a signé avec les rangers du Texas.*). Mais le releveur de fin de partie est justement utilisé en fin de partie et ce n'est pas le lanceur du match; on dit même qu'il vient protéger, sauvegarder la partie. Ce rôle plutôt défensif de fin de partie ne convient pas très bien au vendeur.</sub>

<sub>2. Le *finisseur* tout court vient aussi s'appuyer sur une idée un peu différente : le [*strong finisher*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&index=alt&__index=alt&srchtxt=STRONG%20FINISHER) en anglais, c'est-à-dire celui *qui termine une épreuve en force, en puissance*; et qui rejoint l'idée de mener à bout. Des adjectifs comme *fort* et *puissant* pourraient aussi qualifier un(e) tel(le) vendeur(-euse). Par ailleurs, des [expressions](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&index=alt&__index=alt&srchtxt=AGGRESSIVE%20SELLER) comme vendeur [*dynamique*](http://www.granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=19051388), *entreprenant*, *énergique* pourraient avoir certaines connotations qu'on devra vérifier pour éviter le vendeur du type *terminator*.</sub>

Comment: Yes, I think finisseur is best; a noun that stands on its own without any negative connotation. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

There's no such word in French like “closer”. You can say :

> Un excellent vendeur

It means “an excellent seller”. Where I come from (Québec), people will often say literally the word “closer”.

Answer (score 2):

The only acceptation of the noun [listed in the Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/closer) relates to baseball. In this case, it is translated as [*stoppeur*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stoppeur_%28baseball%29).

In the context of sales, the word probably alludes to "closing a deal" successfully. There is no clear translation, so here are a few suggestions, to add to [milk2go](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/7753/milk2go)'s (from the most to the least formal):

> un vendeur performant,
>
> un vendeur concluant,
>
> un pro de la transformation,
>
> un crack de la vente,
>
> un top vendeur.

Comment: All these are modified nouns, using adjectives. I'm looking for a noun that can stand by itself.

Comment: I just guess: when a complex sales is made, the "closer" is the seller that make you sign papers. he "close" the deal (as mention in @adulte's answer) . One can think of "finaliser l'achat". Unfortunatly neither  "finalisateur"  nor "finaliseur"  exists ...

Comment: "un pro de la transformation"??

Comment: @JeromeJ référence au Rugby. Après avoir marqué un essai, il transforme l'essai...

Comment: "closing a deal" se traduit très bien par "conclure une affaire/un marché/un accord", qui  porte bien le sens *mener à bien*, *mener à son terme avec succès*. Malheureusement, un *vendeur concluant* ou bien un **conclueur* ne se disent pas!

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any word to translate "closer" in french.

In fact maybe some people would say "Un crack de la vente", which would just mean "An excellent seller" to talk about someone very good, but it can be used in many other domains and not only to talk about persons but also animals and living things in general.

Then, "This horse is the best for races" could be translated as "Ce cheval est un crack de la course".

Comment: One could say "as de la vente" or "commercial hors pair".

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I'm French, I didn't know the word 'closer' before for salespeople. Do you want to translate closer for a great salespeople like 'He work very hard so he's a great salespeople' which would be 'un bon/excellant vendeur' or 'He had done lot of studies to be a great salespeople' which would be more 'un commercial'